# AWS Glue python shell job can call AWS glue spark job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am new to AWS GLUE and just want to solve a particular problem. Currently i have only Glue service available only and no EC2 node no lambda.
I am trying to run a AWS spark glue job from Aws python shell glue job . is that possible to run a AWS glue python shell job as a wrapper and call multiple time the same AWS glue spark job with different parameters.
I tried to run the below code snipet but getting boto Ecxeption error in logs.

```
import boto3
glue = boto3.client(service_name='glue', region_name='us-east-1',
              endpoint_url='https://glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com')  
myNewJobRun = glue.start_job_run(JobName='WHICH I CREATED IN CONSOLE')
```

In the above code i have already created a job in console and wants to hit the job from AWS python shell glue job.

Below i want to get the status of job if it is running then it will wait for some time and then again check the status.

```
status = glue.get_job_run(JobName=myJob['Name'], RunId=JobRun['JobRunId'])
```

Can someone advice for share any code sample for reference

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following is a sample code which keeps checking the job status till the job is SUCCEEDED and raises an exception if any of the error state is observed:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(service_name='glue', region_name='us-east-1',
          endpoint_url='https://glue.us-east-1.amazonaws.com') 
response = client.start_job_run(JobName='WHICH U CREATED IN CONSOLE')
status = client.get_job_run(JobName=job_name, RunId=response['JobRunId'])

if status:
    state = status['JobRun']['JobRunState']
    while state not in ['SUCCEEDED']:
        time.sleep(30)
        status = client.get_job_run(JobName=job_name, RunId=response['JobRunId'])
        state = status['JobRun']['JobRunState']
        if state in ['STOPPED', 'FAILED', 'TIMEOUT']:
            raise Exception('Failed to execute glue job: ' + status['JobRun']['ErrorMessage'] + '. State is : ' + state)
```

You can modify the conditions and sleep time as per your requirement.

Comment: Just want to understand the above code can be run on glue python shell job ?  I donot have any EC2 or Lambda function available to me

Comment: this will work as long as boto3 library is available there. However you don't even need to go to python shell. You can execute this code from you local machine by configuring the aws access key and secrete key.

Comment: As per AWS documentation python shell job supports boto3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html

Comment: Sorry but i donot have access to keys i am running this with console only. Thanks for the info

Comment: Let me know in case you face any issues on python shell. Also the access keys are attached your aws account. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/wheres-my-secret-access-key/

Answer (score 1):

What is error?

You may have to add arguments to start_job_run()

> response = glue.start_job_run(
>                       JobName=jobName, Arguments=arguments, AllocatedCapacity=dpus)
>
> status = glue.get_job_run(JobName=jobName,
>                                                RunId=response['JobRunId'])

Comment: Please find below the error . is the approach to solve this is correct ?
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-1BaCUr/J307_wrapper.py", line 4, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions
.
ClientError

Comment: Approach is not good as you are unnecessarily going to keep python shell job running and adding cost. All you want is to run glue job recursively. In that case following approach should work:
1. Run first instance of spark glue job from python shell job
2. From first instance of spark glue job, run next instance of same glue job
3. Keep doing step 2 in loop
4. Add some param to spark glue job to get out of loop.

Comment: Approach is not good as you are unnecessarily going to keep python shell job running and adding cost. All you want is to run glue job recursively. In that case following approach should work:

1.  Run first instance of spark glue job from python shell job

2.  From first instance of spark glue job, run next instance of same glue job

3.  Keep doing step 2 in loop

4.  Add some param to spark glue job to get out of loop.

5. You may have to change spark job config to enable 3 instances to run at same time.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i have implemented the code buy using wrong approach but just want to make the code correct. So i just want to undestand how i would be able to get the Job Id , Status and runtime with in the spark job loop. Since this can only be done using boto3 and thier is  no API within Glue job to get the status of the job. So could you suggest something